# Personalize an awhemes theme on Tkinter ttk - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, ttk

I'm developing a python application with Tkinter and I'm using the awdark theme from awthemes to give my app a standout look. The theme look really good but I realized by looking at the [awthemes website](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/awthemes) that it's possible to personalize the themes by changing for example the graphics color with `setHighlightColor`. There seems to be a lot of customization possible but they don't show concrete examples in python, just some piece of code like this:

```
package require awthemes
::themeutils::setHighlightColor awdark #007000
package require awdark
```

After several tries I didn't manage to customize the theme and I didn't find anything on google either, so I'm asking for your help.

Here is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

# Create some random widgets to see the changes
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
global_frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)
global_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
notebook.add(global_frame, text="Tab1")
ttk.Radiobutton(global_frame, text="Radio 1").grid(row=0, column=0)
ttk.Radiobutton(global_frame, text="Radio 2").grid(row=0, column=1)
ttk.Progressbar(global_frame, value=75).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Create a style and import the awdark theme
style = ttk.Style()
root.tk.call('lappend', 'auto_path', '/Users/marinnagy/Downloads/awthemes-10.4.0')
root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'awdark')
style.theme_use('awdark')

root.mainloop()
```

The current GUI look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrTIS.png), how to change the graphics color to green like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnjkJ.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
...
# Create a style and import the awdark theme
style = ttk.Style()
root.tk.call('lappend', 'auto_path', '/Users/marinnagy/Downloads/awthemes-10.4.0')
root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'awthemes')
root.tk.call('::themeutils::setHighlightColor', 'awdark', '#007000')
root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'awdark')
style.theme_use('awdark')
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do I have to call each modification with a new ```root.tk.call``` line or is there a simpler and less repetitive way, with a .tcl file for example?

Comment: @MarinNagy I am not an expert on TCL, so I cannot provide sample `.tcl`.  I think you need to execute `root.tk.call()` for each modification.

Comment: @MarinNagy If this answer has solved your issue, consider to accept it as the answer.